# How to negotiate ESOP scheme after signing work contract?

Tags: salary, negotiation, benefits

I am about to start a new job at a tech firm. The original offer includes base salary + ESOP (employee stock ownership plan) scheme. The contract I've signed so far is not concerned with the ESOP package (that has been mentioned only in the letter of intent). They explained that I will sign the ESOP package after starting.

Unfortunately, I failed to read the ESOP package terms carefully and I now found a term that states that If I resign voluntarily before x years (where x is a relatively big number of years after the cliff period - and it covers the whole vesting period), I lose all vested options. I was surprised to see that since in the offer letter (as well as during the recruiting calls) the compensation was expressed as an annual estimate (including base salary + ESOP) - without reading the second document carefully it is hard to imagine that you lose the vested shares. Normal tenure at the company is way below the x amount of years also.

I wonder, how can I now negotiate for better terms given that I haven't yet signed the ESOP package? Could I ask to update those terms upon good performance in the first year?

To add a bit more context; At the period of signing the contract, I had significant negotiation leverage that I didn't actually exercise, as I was getting competing offers that, in retrospect, had better terms in them.

Comment: You may want to reword this to downplay the "ESOP" part which few people are familiar with and because it's not really relevant. It's important to mention that your issue with the remuneration is it being conditioned on staying a (high) number of years but the rest of it won't affect answers.

Comment: @Lilienthal at what point do you think I could negotiate for the number of years? What are the steps you think I can take now to make this easier for the future? I'll have a chat with the team this week to discuss this.

Comment: It is usual to lose vested options unless you exercise them (buy them at the strike price) but then those are yours.  Do you mean the terms say you can’t exercise or lose exercised options?

Comment: @mxyzplk-SEstopbeingevil this is not a public company - they are looking into an IPO in the next 5 years. The only exercise option is likely going to be an IPO, a 50% buyout seems very unlikely. So yes, if I have an exercise option before the x years, indeed I can get the value out of the vested options. For this, the terms state "you lose vested/unvested options"

Comment: Right, you should be able to exercise them as soon as they vest.  If you don’t (usually there’s a 30-90 day grace persons to do so when you exit) you lose them when you leave.  That’s universal in my experience.

Comment: Good learning opportunity. When negotiating salary only what´s written a signed really counts - everything else is just a bonus you should be ok with to live without.

Comment: @mxyzplk-SEstopbeingevil But I won’t have any exercise option the moment they vest. As I said, currently it’s a private company

Comment: You do have an exercise option.  It uses the strike price in your options agreement.  This is how all “still private” startups work. I work for a 10 person seed round startup.  I vest shares yearly.  I can exercise them at the current strike price by cutting a check to the company.  If I do I own them and own part of the company.  If I do not, I retain the “option” to (why they are called options) till either there’s an IPO or buyout or till I leave.

Comment: @mxyzplk-SEstopbeingevil I wish it was like that. Many private startups, including the one I work for now and the one I am going to, don't allow for exercising unless there is an event like IPO or buyout.

Answer (score 5):

> I wonder, how can I now negotiate for better terms given that I
>   haven't yet signed the ESOP package? Could I ask to update those terms
>   upon good performance in the first year?

You can always ask. Unfortunately, unless you are willing to walk away from the job, you have no leverage. Even after the first year, signalling that you don't expect to be around for the duration of the vesting period might not be a wise move.

In my experience, terms like these aren't that unusual. Clearly they are designed as an incentive to stick around. Perhaps this company will bend their normal practices to keep you happy. In my experience, most companies will not.

Ask yourself - if you had fully understood what you read about the ESOP package terms, and assuming those terms weren't negotiable, would have have rejected this job offer?

If so, then you should now be willing to walk away from this job and turn to one of the competing offers. If not, then just accept that you are getting less than you hoped, but exactly what was offered.

In either case, chalk this up as a lesson learned regarding how carefully you must read all documents before making an important decision.

Comment: In both cases I'll need to chalk this, and take this lesson (: It's hard to imagine that those terms would have been completely non-negotiable.

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee everything is negotiable, but you likely lack the necessary leverage.

Comment: At this moment yes, what would be some negotiation strategy for when I do have some leverage? (staying at a job and becoming valuable employee, in most cases creates leverage)

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee Are you severely below market? I don't usually recommend it but sometimes it makes sense to chalk a job up as a loss and move on immediately leaving it off your resume. Only if you're willing to do that can you realistically address this with your employer now using the "I wouldn't have accepted had I known" but there are obvious downsides.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I think considering different options is a given (walking away from a job) if you don't feel the compensation is where it should be. That said, I am obviously really interested in the company I've signed the contract with, hence I'd like to create a situation where I feel I am rewarded fairly.

Comment: @Lilienthal not severely. Base salary is the market median for the role/level. Plus the company is a big step up in reputation and branding, as well as opportunities for meaningful contribution. But in my field, a year from now can yield much better offers. The ESOP, as structured, actually reduces the likelihood to stay long term - as it introduces higher risk for the employee.

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee You could definitely raise that as a topic, just keep in mind that Joe's answer here is very accurate and this discussion itself can raise questions around commitment to stay.

Comment: @Lilienthal I don't believe too much in the notion described here, and I don't have evidence suggesting this is common as Joe states. On the contrary, most reward schemes I've encountered tend to be more beneficial. I also believe that negotiating for compensation that is market-competitive is beneficial for both parties and doesn't show lack of motivation to stay. The opposite actually

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee: I don´t think your leverage grows, the opposite is the case. The longer you work there, the more you are locked in by the fact that you would loose your options when you resign. OTOH stock may or may not be worse something, so if your base salary is not enough to keep you happy, you should maybe reconsider after all...

Comment: @Daniel assuming someone can become a valuable employee - Shouldn't they normally have the leverage to negotiate for improving their compensation - or terms of their compensation? It shouldn't be hard to make a fair case for owning your vested options sooner - when this is what is offered by the competition for hiring tech employees

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee: So what´s your plan when they decide to play a game of chicken with you? You risk loosing your options, they risk loosing you (which will probably save them money, because they are keeping the stocks). A lot of managers do not react too well on the kind of "pay up or I´ll leave" negotiation.

Comment: @Daniel I guess, to walk into a negotiation like that requires having a backup plan that you are happy to take, knowing what you lose. Fairly negotiating my compensation has worked, for me, in the past with mutual benefit. If we were to follow your logic, they should not give share options to anyone, as it loses them money.

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee: No it saves them money. As you said yourself, you had better offers if you did not factor in the ESOP.  If they didn´t pay you partly in shares, they´d probably have to borrow that money somewhere, with interest (assuming they even get it). I also binds employees and ties them more closely to the companies success, which helps them make (more) money.

Comment: @Daniel As we agreed earlier, both parties have something to gain and something to lose in such a negotiation. The fact that you have vested shares does not prohibit you from finding better offers, with more attractive share packages for example. But, as you point out, this doesn't mean that the company will change its strategy to retain you. I guess both are possible outcomes. in other words, yes - it saves them money. But, they also lose money by not retaining good employees. New hires are frequently the most expensive asset for companies

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee I agree with you, only in my experience, sadly, a lot of businesses don´t really understand human capital. Also its easier to convince somebody to agree to X if the want to get it (you) than to pay more for something they already have. My point is, don´t take a job in hopes of uncertain future rewards if you (emotionally or financially) depend on it. If you are OK with a gamble then it´s fine.

Answer (score 1):

"where x is a relatively big number of years after the cliff period - and it covers the whole vesting period), I lose all vested options"

That is a serious red flag as it essentially extends your cliff period and completely removes the vesting. What happens if they fire you?

And the fact that signing the ESOP was postponed looks like they wanted you not to look too closely into that contract.

Is it possible that there is a misunderstanding? Losing vested options because you leave is exactly the opposite of what normally happens and is very surprising. What is the meaning of the vesting period in that case?

Comment: I think the ESOP contract will include the terms described in the docs they have shared - so I don't think that is a play - that said; I do want to look into the terms closely but if I find something weird I don't know how I can react. Losing the shares happens in case of voluntarily resigning. In case of being fired (I assume) you maintain them. In that case vesting period is there to decide how much you have in case of exit before the x years (my understanding).

Comment: How likely is an exit in the closer future? "In case of being fired (I assume) you maintain them." such an asymmetry sounds strange. It would mean that you'd have to actively make them fire you to keep your shares.

Comment: I should word it differently. X years is the complete vesting period (not more). They also state that after the vesting period you are entitled to the full amount regardless of resigning or being fired. IPO is in the plans, but probably not sooner than 3-4 years from now

Comment: So essentially your cliff is now X years.

Comment: Yep it looks like it :/